# Code to export control image to bmp file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to export a button bmp data to a bmp file.

For example, suppose I have assigned an image to a button using the wizard, Then I want some code to export that image to the filesystem (image.bmp).

Is there a simple instruction or instructions for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the bitmap image data by using the `.PictureData` property of the Command button, and then write the data to a `.bmp` file using an `ADODB.Stream` object:

```vbs
Dim strm As New ADODB.Stream
strm.Type = adTypeBinary
strm.Open
strm.Write Me.Command0.PictureData
strm.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\ButtonImage.bmp"
strm.Close
Set strm = Nothing
```